# How to define "wstring"?

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, wstring

I get error during build in `Ubuntu`.
And the error is as following:

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of `wstring' with no type
```

In order to solve this problem,I have to define the `wstring` by myself.
So who knows how to define `wstring`?

Comment: You should `#include<string>`  and use `std::wstring`

Comment: I have added #include<string> and used its fully qualified name std::wstring.So,I have to define the wstring,because the gcc I have used do not support it.So,How to define “wstring”?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `wstring` you have to add `#include<string>` and, preferrably, use its fully qualified name `std::wstring`.

**UPDATE:**
In the case that your compiler, for some reason, does not support `std::wstring`, you can try with the following `typedef` (taken directly from `bits/string_fwd.h` and tweaked to add the missing `std::`).

```
typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;
```

Note that this depends on `wchar_t` being defined, and according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wchar_t/):

> In C++, wchar_t is a distinct fundamental type (and thus it is not defined in  nor any other header).

If your compiler doesn't have support for `wchar_t` there's no (easy) way to define it as far as I know.

Comment: Dear Alberto Miranda,I have added #include<string> and use its fully qualified name std::wstring.So,I have to define the wstring,because the gcc I have used do not support it.So,How to define “wstring”?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question properly. If your compiler doesn't support it you can try with the following: `typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;` though it depends on whether yout compiler supports `wchar_t` or not.